# How to change the current edited class using getElementsByClass?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using getElementsByClass and trying to replace the input box with the div having class only. But in my code, I am using array 0.

```
document.getElementsByClassName("item")[0].innerHTML = value;
```

But I want to replace only current edited input box only

http://jsfiddle.net/Gr4yy/29/

Comment: There are no input boxes the in fiddle.  Can you clarify your question and show exactly what you expect after replacement?

Comment: @MichaelGaskill On the click of div the div got replaced with the input box  dynamically

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
var cnt=0;
$(document).on("click", ".item", function () {
cnt++;
var input = $('<input />', {
    'type': 'text',
    'id': 'edit-text'+cnt,
    'class': 'edit-text',
    'value': $(this).text()
});
$(this).replaceWith(input);

$(document).on("blur", ".edit-text", function () {

        var value = $(this).val();
        $(this).replaceWith('<div class="item">'+value+'</div>');


});
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I think what you trying to do can be done with css only, using JS is just a bit of overkill

```
input {
  display: block;
}
.noinput {
  border-style: none;
  background-color: transparent;
}
.noinput:focus {
  border: 1px solid #000000;
  background-color: #ffffff;
}


<input class="noinput" type="text" placeholder="Date" value="">
<input class="noinput" type="text" placeholder="Date" value="">
<input class="noinput" type="text" placeholder="Date" value="">
```

https://jsfiddle.net/ndcdwx8q/

Ok, as you have to use Jquery... it can be done quite easily

```
$('.item').click(function (e) {

    var $currnetDiv = $(this); // it will be used to replace input on blur
    var divText = $currnetDiv.text();

    /* create input element with text from div as value*/
    var $input = $('<input type="text">').val(divText);

    $currnetDiv.replaceWith($input); 

    /* on blur simply replace current input with previously cached div*/
    $input.focus().blur(function(){ 
      $currnetDiv.text($(this).val()); //grab value form input and append it as text to the div
      $input.replaceWith($currnetDiv);
    });

  });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Gr4yy/36/

Comment: This is a nice way too. but in my project i got the div only to perform action

Comment: @Bhawna I added Jquery answer, kept css part as I think it is nice solution :)

Answer (score 0):

You can add the innerHtml while replacing the control

```
$(document).on("click", ".item", function () {
        var input = $('<input />', {
            'type': 'text',
            'id': 'edit-text',
            'value': $(this).text()
        });
        $(this).replaceWith(input);
        document.getElementById("edit-text").focus();
        $(document).on("blur change", "#edit-text", function () {
            setTimeout(function () {
                var value = input.val();
                input.replaceWith('<div class="item">'+value+'</div>');
                //document.getElementsByClassName("item")[0].innerHTML = value;
            }, 100);
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(document).on("click", ".item", function () {
 var input = $('<input />', {
        'type': 'text',
        'id': 'edit-text',
        'value': $(this).text()
    });
   $(this).replaceWith(input);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="item">editing text</div>
<div class="item">Date</div>
<div class="item">Date</div>
<div class="item">Date</div>
<div class="item">Date</div>
<div class="item">Date</div>
<div class="item">Date</div>
```